# How to get direction of a language by its local code? (RTL or LTR)

Tags: php, internationalization, locale, multilingual, intl

Using PHP builtin functions and extensions (in particular intl) how to get direction of a language by its local code? (RTL or LTR)

Answer (score 2):

There is something from Unicode called "Unicode Common Locale Data Repository", i.e. CLDR, which provide exactly this piece of information.

You can see [this page](http://cldr.unicode.org/cldr-features#TOC-Language-and-script-information:) which introduce what kind of features are available in CLDR, which include script direction.

As a note, script direction aren't just ltr or rtl, there are other directions as well.

And then, for access via PHP, you can look at e.g. [Punic](https://punic.github.io) or any other library that would come up when you search PHP and CLDR together on google.

```
/**
 * Retrieve the character order (right-to-left or left-to-right).
 *
 * @param string $locale The locale to use. If empty we'll use the default locale set in \Punic\Data
 *
 * @return string Return 'left-to-right' or 'right-to-left'
 */
public static function getCharacterOrder($locale = '')
{
    $data = Data::get('layout', $locale);
    return $data['characterOrder'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The php Intl extension is based on CLDR and this question was looking to see if its possible to fetch direction from locale using this extension. Thanks for refering Punic.

Comment: With Punic you can call:

    \Punic\Misc::getCharacterOrder();

which returns 'left-to-right' or 'right-to-left'